# How to show contact form popup in same page

Tags: php

I'm designing my WordPress Website. I don't want my visitors to go for new page on clicking the contact us/get in touch button. I want my form to show up as popup (only when clicked on button).

Comment: Many (if not all) contact form plugins let you place the forms anywhere, not just on their own pages. Which one are you using? Or did you mean as a pop-up lightbox or something?

Comment: Hi thanks for an answer. Yes. Its more like a pop-up. I don't want user to go for new page when he clicks on "get in touch" button. Instead he should get the form in the samepage itself as a pop-up (only when he clicks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Contact Form 7 which is usually one of the popular free plugins you can use shortcode to display forms on a normal page by copying this into the editor and editing the form ID and title as needed.

```
[contact-form-7 id="1234" title="Contact form 1"]
```

EDIT:
You can use simply jQuery to hide/show the form

https://codepen.io/AKiwi92/pen/mdJBpPg

Comment: Hi thanks for an answer, but I had put my question in wrong way I guess.  I don't want user to go for new page when he clicks on "get in touch" button. Instead he should get the form in the samepage itself as a pop-up (only when he clicks)

Comment: @VinayKumarLUpdated my answer!

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood :)

Comment: @VinayKumarL no problem! If my answer helped if you could mark it as the answer it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I did it.. thank you once again. :)